# GIT - cannot push to remote EC2 server after removing local repositiory

Tags: git

I have a local `.git` repo, a repo on Bitbucket (`origin`) and also a bare repo set up on a remote EC2 server (`remote1`). I have been committing locally and pushing to both `origin` and `remote1` for some months. I recently decided to remove my local git repository and start a fresh by creating a new local repo using `git init`, then adding my local files and committing them. I can push to `origin` just fine (because I also re-created the repo on Bitbucket, so the commit history marrys up). However, when I try to force push to the `remote1`, I get the following message thrown by SmartGit (a GIT GUI):

> The push has been forced, but was still rejected. This usually means
>   that the branch in the remote repository has changed since your last
>   fetch and pushing your commits would overwrite commits in the remote
>   repository which you have never seen. If you actually want to
>   overwrite these commits, pull them first, then force-push again.

This kinda makes sense in so far as the commit history no longer marrys up, however I really just want to be able to push and overwrite any commit history with whatever I have locally.

My instinct was to log on to `remote1` and run `git init --bare`, but I still get the above message.

Incidentally, I ran the following command locally, via git bash:

```
git push -u remote1 master
```

and received the following message:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> > Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> >     exists.

Now I'm really confused as to what might be the cause and how to fix it - any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Did you properly remove/delete the existing remote repo before running `git init --bare`? Simply re-initializing will not delete a repository's commit history.

If not that, verify your remote is in fact setup correctly with the url and file path. `git ls-remote remote1` will output an error if it can't ping your remote repo successfully.

Comment: Yes, i did remove the remote repo before executing git init --bare.